# Debian 8 is not using the latest kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, boot

I need to update the kernel of an old headless server (small machine logging some instruments). Alas I cannot upgrade beyond Debian 8 Jessie.

Some Virtualbox modules I need are only available for `3.16.0-11-amd64` and not for `3.16.0-4-amd64`:

```
$ cat /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.dep | grep vbox
<NOTHING>

$ cat /lib/modules/3.16.0-11-amd64/modules.dep | grep vbox
updates/dkms/vboxnetflt.ko: updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
updates/dkms/vboxnetadp.ko: updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
updates/dkms/vboxpci.ko: updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko:
```

The system has been upgraded and rebooted.

There are now 3 available kernel images:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image

ii  linux-image-3.16.0-10-amd64    3.16.81-1                        amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-11-amd64    3.16.84-1                        amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64     3.16.43-2+deb8u5                 amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64              3.16+63+deb8u7                   amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

According to my understanding, at boot the newest one should be picked, but something strange happens:

```
$ uname -a

Linux bluelikon-mini-abgebaut 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Is there a way to force using `3.16.0-11-amd64`?**

**Is there perhaps a configuration file in Debian that is forcing `3.16.0-4-amd64` instead?**

Online I found that it is quite easy to change `grub` settings to add the new kernel (all examples refer to `grub`, i.e. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/427564/how-to-force-debian-to-boot-new-kernel)), **but in my system `grub` is not used.**

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps by looking at the contents of `/boot` you can see which bootloader is used and then set it up to boot that certain kernel you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the contents of /boot you can see which bootloader is used and then set it up to boot that certain kernel you need.

Comment: You got it. It is using syslinux as a bootloader. Changing the image name in /boot/syslinux.cfg did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The kernel you're running solely depends on your bootloader. Found out what it is and set it up to boot the required kernel version.